# Rails logs not working correctly in production

Tags: ruby-on-rails, logging

Something is wrong with the logs. They work fine on development, but in production I can't write my own messages.

I haven't changed anything in the configuration files, other than installing Devise and Mongoid. But just in case, I tried uncommenting the line #config.log_level = :debug in production.rb

Controller:

```
class PagesController < ApplicationController
  def home
    logger.fatal 'bla'
  end

  def about
  end
end
```

Terminal (log permissions):

```
root@ubuntu:/srv/www/myapp# ls log -lah
total 496K
drwxr-xr-x  2 myapp root    4.0K 2012-02-21 17:18 .
drwxr-xr-x 14 root  root    4.0K 2012-02-20 14:54 ..
-rw-r--r--  1 myapp myapp    35K 2012-02-21 16:23 development.log
-rw-r--r--  1 myapp root       0 2012-02-17 18:27 .gitkeep
-rw-r--r--  1 root  root    447K 2012-02-21 17:47 passenger.80.log
-rw-r--r--  1 myapp myapp      0 2012-02-21 17:18 production.log
```

Terminal (passenger):

```
root@ubuntu:/srv/www/myapp# passenger start -e production -p 80 --user=myapp
=============== Phusion Passenger Standalone web server started ===============
PID file: /srv/www/myapp/tmp/pids/passenger.80.pid
Log file: /srv/www/myapp/log/passenger.80.log
Environment: production
Accessible via: http://0.0.0.0/

You can stop Phusion Passenger Standalone by pressing Ctrl-C.
===============================================================================
cache: [HEAD /] miss
cache: [GET /] miss
```

Comment: Is the production log being created, but just not being written to? If so, that at least shows that the app has write permissions to that directory.  If that production log was already existed, then are you sure you're looking in the right place for the new log?  In my app, where the app is deployed using Capistrano, the logs are in a different directory.

Comment: @snips Yes it's being created in log/production.log (you can see the permissions in the original post) but nothing being is written into it. I have never used Capistrano yet, it looks too complicated, so I don't know about that.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Assuming you're on Rails 3.2.0 or Rails 3.2.1, this is a known issue (see https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/4277). It's already been fixed, but hasn't been released yet.

A workaround is to add an initializer with:

```
Rails.logger.instance_variable_get(:@logger).instance_variable_get(:@log_dest).sync = true if Rails.logger
```

Update: Rails 3.2.2 fixes this.

Comment: Thank God. I was already thinking about going back to PHP. I have been saved.

Comment: Rails 3.2.2.rc1 came out today, fixing this. The final 3.2.2 should be released next week.